# R: loop nested with for change in parallel with foreach

Tags: r, for-loop, parallel-processing, nested-loops, parallel.foreach

I'm trying to convert my nested loop in parallel code with foreach. I don't understand how to do this.
follow my code:
thank in advance at all!!

```
setwd("simul")
IntervalTime <- c(10,15,20)
ThinIntesity <- c(10,15,20,25)
MINSTOCKGROW <- c(200,250,300)
meteoScen <- c("rcp4p5", "rcp8p5")
Co2mod <- c("CO2_rcp4p5", "CO2_rcp8p5")
fileSettings <- c("set_co2_on_man_off.txt", "set_co2_on_man_on.txt")
mapUnc <- data.frame()
uncerOut <- data.frame()
mapUncNoMan <- data.frame()
validation <- list()

Sample <- getSample(resDE,thin=700,start=0.3*niter,coda=F)
nSample <- nrow(Sample)
ValidationOutput <- "./output/"
#FOR MANAGEMENT CASES
```

Here the code for parallelization, but I tried different methods but only one core work

```
for (i in 1:length(IntervalTime)){
  for(p in 1:length(MINSTOCKGROW)){
    for (j in 1:length(ThinIntesity)){
      for(z in 1:length(meteoScen)){
        for (k in 1:nSample){
          # MAP BAYESIAN REFERENCE
          ps <- createMixWithDefaults(pars = Sample[k, ],defaults = paramDefault, parind)
          if (meteoScen[z]=="M45"){
            #running the model
            unlink(list.files("./output/Validation",full.names = TRUE),recursive=TRUE)
            validation <- run3DCMCC(modelrun)
            validation$annual$MINSTOCKGROW <- MINSTOCKGROW[p]
            validation$annual$Management <- paste0(meteoScen[z],"_","IV_",IntervalTime[i],"_","IT_",ThinIntesity[j])
            validation$annual$CODE <- paste0(meteoScen[z],"_","IV_",IntervalTime[i],"_","IT_",ThinIntesity[j],"_",MINSTOCKGROW[p],"_",validation$annual$YEAR)
            validation$annual$Thinintensity <- ThinIntesity[j]
            validation$annual$intervTime <- IntervalTime[i]

            validation$annual$Meteo <- meteoScen[z]
            validation$annual$Manage <- "MANAGEMENT"
            validation$annual$Harv_Wood <- cumsum(validation$annual$C_HW)
            validation$annual$StockCarbon <- validation$annual$Harv_Wood+validation$annual$STANDING_WOOD

            # validation$monthly$Date <- as.yearmon(paste0(validation$monthly$YEAR, "-", validation$monthly$MONTH))
            # validation$monthly$Management <- paste0("METEO_",meteoScenario[z],"INTERVAL_",IntervalTime[i],"INTENSITY_",ThinIntesity[j])
            validationDF <- data.frame(validation$annual)
            write.table(validationDF, paste0("./dataOut/",meteoScen[z],"_IV_",IntervalTime[i],"_IT_",ThinIntesity[j],"_MINSTCK_",MINSTOCKGROW[p],"_MAN_ON",".txt"),quote = F, sep = "\t",row.names = F,col.names = T)
            mapUnc <- rbind(mapUnc, validation$annual)

          } else {
```

a condition inside of nested loop

```
            ps <- createMixWithDefaults(pars = Sample[k, ],defaults = paramDefault,parind)
            #running the model
            unlink(list.files("./output/",full.names = TRUE),recursive=TRUE)
            validation <- run3DCMCC(modelrun)
            validation$annual$MINSTOCKGROW <- MINSTOCKGROW[p]
            validation$annual$Management <- paste0(meteoScen[z],"_","IV_",IntervalTime[i],"_","IT_",ThinIntesity[j])
            validation$annual$CODE <- paste0(meteoScen[z],"_","IV_",IntervalTime[i],"_","IT_",ThinIntesity[j],"_",validation$annual$YEAR)
            validation$annual$Thinintensity <- ThinIntesity[j]
            validation$annual$intervTime <- IntervalTime[i]
            validation$annual$Meteo <- meteoScen[z]
            validation$annual$Manage <- "MANAGEMENT"
            validation$annual$Harv_Wood <- cumsum(validation$annual$C_HW)
            validation$annual$StockCarbon <- validation$annual$Harv_Wood+validation$annual$STANDING_WOOD

            validationDF <- data.frame(validation$annual)
            write.table(validationDF, paste0("./dataOut/",meteoScen[z],"_","IV_",IntervalTime[i],"_","IT_",ThinIntesity[j],"_MAN_ON",".txt"),quote = F, sep = "\t",row.names = F,col.names = T)
```

rbind for all run model

```
mapUnc <- rbind(mapUnc, validation$annual)

          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you may not need any `for` loop. Consider `expand.grid` on your input vectors which returns a `data.frame` of all possible combinations. Then, run `Map` (variant of `mapply`) passing column values iteratively and element-wise through a function that builds *vaildationDF*. And `Map()` will then return a list of dataframes equal to rows of expand grid df (i.e., all combinations).

Of course, since you provide no reproducible example, unknown libraries, and function calls, below is just a sketch of the process. Also your `if/else` conditions look practically the same, but below is a rewrite of `if` clause. Also, some lines seem redundant as *ps* object is never used (hence *Sample* is not incorporated below). Possibly *ps* is tied to *modelrun*? And `unlink()` does not look to affect items in loop:

```
IntervalTime <- c(10,15,20)          # passed as i variable in fct. via Map()
ThinIntesity <- c(10,15,20,25)       # passed as t variable in fct. via Map() 
MINSTOCKGROW <- c(200,250,300)       # passed as g variable in fct. via Map()
meteoScen <- c("rcp4p5", "rcp8p5")   # passed as m variable in fct. via Map()

loopdf <- expand.grid(IntervalTime=IntervalTime, 
                      ThinIntensity=ThinIntesity, 
                      MINSTOCKGROW=MINSTOCKGROW, 
                      meteoScen=meteoScen)

createValidationDF <- function (i, t, g, m) {

  validation <- run3DCMCC(modelrun)
  validation$annual$MINSTOCKGROW <- g
  validation$annual$Management <- paste0(m,"_","IV_", i,"_","IT_", t)
  validation$annual$CODE <- paste0(m,"_","IV_",i,"_","IT_", t,"_",g,"_",
                                   validation$annual$YEAR)
  validation$annual$Thinintensity <- t
  validation$annual$intervTime <- i

  validation$annual$Meteo <- m
  validation$annual$Manage <- "MANAGEMENT"
  validation$annual$Harv_Wood <- cumsum(validation$annual$C_HW)
  validation$annual$StockCarbon <- validation$annual$Harv_Wood+validation$annual$STANDING_WOOD

  validationDF <- data.frame(validation$annual)

  write.table(validationDF, paste0("./dataOut/", m ,"_IV_", i,"_IT_", t,"_MINSTCK_",  g,"_MAN_ON",".txt"),
              quote = F, sep = "\t",row.names = F,col.names = T)

  return(validationDF)
}

df_List <- Map(createValidationDF, loopdf$IntervalTime, loopdf$ThinIntensity,
                                   loopdf$MINSTOCKGROW, loopdf$meteoScen)

mapUnc <- do.call(rbind, df_List)
```